# Two multi-level push menus on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design

I want to implement two multi-level push menus on one page, one on my left hand side (ltr) and one on the right (rtl)

Has anyone had any luck doing this? I've tried the below where #menu is my slide-in from the left, #search is my slide-in from the right and #pushobj is my site content, but it ends up making neither slide-in work.

```
$( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu({
    containersToPush: [$( '#pushobj' )],
    fullCollapse: true,
    collapsed:true,
    mode:'cover',
    menuWidth: '100%',
    // Just for fun also changing the look of the menu
    wrapperClass: 'mlpm_w',
    menuInactiveClass: 'mlpm_inactive'
});

$( '#search' ).multilevelpushmenu({
    containersToPush: [$( '#pushobj' )],
    fullCollapse: true,
    collapsed:true,
    mode:'cover',
    menuWidth: '100%',
    direction: 'rtl', 
    // Just for fun also changing the look of the menu
    wrapperClass: 'mlpm_w',
    menuInactiveClass: 'mlpm_inactive'
});
```

http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/